# Materialize navbar with input field: background-color and text color

Tags: css, materialize

I have a navbar with a title and a text input. The navbar is light red, and the TITLE is easily visible since it is white. However, the placeholder (SEARCH STUFF) in the input is hardly visible since it is grey, and also the text I enter later. I have tried to change the color of the text input, but without success. How can I do that? Is it also possible to change the color of the whole input field so that it is better visible?

[image: Image to current crappy navbar]

```
<div class="navbar-fixed">
<nav>
  <div class="nav-wrapper red lighten-2">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">TITLE</a>
      <ul class="right">
        <li>
          <input id="select" type="text" placeholder="SEARCH STUFF">
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to change `placeholder` color just use the following pseudo-elements

There are three different implementations: pseudo-elements, pseudo-classes, and nothing.

- WebKit, Blink (Safari, Google Chrome, Opera 15+) and Microsoft Edge
  are using a pseudo-element: ::-webkit-input-placeholder. [Ref]
  Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 is using a pseudo-class: :-moz-placeholder
  (one colon).
- Mozilla Firefox 19+ is using a pseudo-element: ::-moz-placeholder,
  but the old selector will still work for a while.
- Internet Explorer 10 and 11 are using a pseudo-class:
  :-ms-input-placeholder.
- April 2017: Most modern browsers
  support the simple pseudo-element ::placeholder

```css
input{
     color:white;
}


input::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit, Blink, Edge */
    color:white;
}

input:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
   color:white;
   opacity:  1;
}

input::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
   color:white;
   opacity:  1;
}
input:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
    color:white;
}
input::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Microsoft Edge */
    color:white;
}

input::placeholder { /* Most modern browsers support this now. */
   color:white;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="navbar-fixed">
<nav>
  <div class="nav-wrapper red lighten-2">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">TITLE</a>
      <ul class="right">
        <li>
          <input id="select" type="text" placeholder="SEARCH STUFF">
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   #select{
        color:#fff;
    }
 ::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit, Blink, Edge */
        color:    #fff;
    }
    :-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
       color:    #fff;
       opacity:  1;
    }
    ::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
       color:    #fff;
       opacity:  1;
    }
    :-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
       color:    #909;
    }
    ::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Microsoft Edge */
       color:    #fff;
    }

    ::placeholder { /* Most modern browsers support this now. */
       color:    #fff;
    }
```